# Automatically check image quality on all images on a website

Tags: images, resolution

Is there a way to automatically check the quality on all images on a website (given I have a list of the URL's)?

During the last 5 years tens of thousand images has been uploaded to my webstore, and I have discovered that a few hundred have crappy resolution (wrong size, blurry image, etc).

Checking manually is too time consuming, so I'm looking for a tool where I can upload a list of URL to all the images - and get a report which displays resolution and image quality of the images.

Preferably an online tool, but alternativley I can download them and check in local software.

All suggestion appreciated. Thanks